# ssh pseudo-tty causes PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh, docker, pty

Here is my setup: Ubuntu 12.04 server that uses Docker containers for services.  Each docker container also runs Ubuntu 12.04.  OpenSSH 5.9p1 used everywhere.

When I run this:

```
ssh root@localhost -p 49167 -i foopy/./ssh/id_rsa
```

I can log in fine, I just get a simple shell where I can't do much (no full screen apps like vi, etc), I forget what that mode is called.

However, if I want to force pseudo-tty using -t like this:

```
ssh -t root@localhost -p 49167 -i foopy/./ssh/id_rsa
```

I get this error and throws me back to the command line:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Any idea why this would be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps fixed in 0.9.1 : https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has mentionned by @shabbychef, This has been fixed in 0.9.1

Comment: That was it, did not think docker would have mattered.

Comment: The issue was that Docker was handling the ptmx stuff only for tty containers. However, sshd needs it and is often run without tty mode. We now make sure that all the pts/ptmx stuff is properly setup all the time.